# Layout not showing in kotlin android studio

Tags: android

Basically when I close android studio and open up, this login.xml layout file always shows up like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN8lv.png)

And it also does not allow to show the design.
This is the content of the file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/loginbackground">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="121dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="121dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="487dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="101dp"
        android:text="@string/signup_suggestion"
        android:textColor="@color/navy"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:backgroundTint="#BFE5F3FF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:text="@string/login_to_ai_planet"
        android:textColor="@color/cloud"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="283dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="260dp"
        android:background="#97E5F3FF"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="283dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="181dp"
        android:background="#97E5F3FF"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="151dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="151dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="152dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="102dp"
        android:background="@color/fern"
        android:text="@string/loginbutton"
        android:textColor="@color/cloud"
        app:backgroundTint="#7A02296C"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Would anyone know how to fix this problem?
The layout works fine until I close android studio and open it up again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create the xml file via the resource manager ? Maybe that could help. Try also to delete .idea folder of this project, reopen android studio and click Build--Rebuild project menu.